# IntelliJ Idea SBT Console - Any way to scroll up/down

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm trying to get to mouse free workflow. 
I can ctrl-tab-0 to get to the console, but can I scroll up and down without using a mouse?

Hopefully this isn't too off base! I have everything else working but sbt console only has one focus point with the ctrl tab shortcut. Is there a way to change focus to the other part of the console with the keyboard?